# Is there a way to arbitrate between two different update sources without a lock?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, locking, lock-free

I am receiving updates from two different sources (network listen) upon which I get a callback to a method somewhat like this:

```
void onUpdate(Update* update)
{
    static MutexT lock;
    static hash_set<UpdateID> set;

    ScopedGuard _(lock); //lock here
    hash_set<UpdateID>::iterator it = set.find(update->id);
    if (it == set.end())
        set.insert(update->id);
    else
        return;

    listener->onUpdate(/*some stuff*/);
}
```

since both sources are feeding you the same updates, you want to avoid notifying on duplicates, you want to arbitrate between both sources to be up to date with the latest from whoever gives it to you first and also for missed updates if one sources is possibly unreliable. The thing is, it's expensive to lock on every update, is there a way around this lock if I definitely do not want duplicate `onUpdate` calls?

(Or at least a way to reduce cost?)

Comment: Do both sources supply an identical stream of updates?

Comment: Have you considered using non-blocking sockets and doing this in a single thread? I mean, what's the gain in using multiple threads if you have a choke-point like that?

Comment: @Kerrek, yes except one is udp so it may drop packets, the other is tcp and is slower

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov Yea I see what you mean. It's really just there being a reliable tcp stream from a slow server and a faster multicast feed. I'm thinking I could have the multicast callback insert into the hash table and callback (lock free) and the slower one grab the lock to check if he's needed or not.

Comment: Hmm... do you have a sequence number in the updates?

Comment: As @KerrekSB is saying, those things usually have sequence numbers, so you only really need to keep last properly processed seq num.

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov true, but in this case they are not sequential messages with increasing sequence numbers.

Comment: If you insist on multiple threads, I think a reasonable design (without knowing all the details) would be to have two single-producer-single-consumer lock-free ring buffers, one from UDP source, one from TCP source, consumed by third processing thread in some round-robin fashion.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do it with at least one arbitrary-sized collection of already-seen IDs. Imagine thread 1 gets packets 1, 5, 6, and only then does thread 2 get 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. Thread 2 must somehow be able to know that packet 5 was received, but no single shared, primitive variable can communicate that (because thread one saw packets 5 and 6 in immediate succession, with no intervening read from thread 2). Is the locked hashset actually very expensive? You should move the `onUpdate` outside the lock, I suppose.

Comment: You're most likely calculating the hash value twice... doing `auto i = set.insert(update->id); if(i.second) listener->onUpdate(/*some stuff*/);` would likely be faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the lock shouldn't be static, it should be a member variable.

You could make it more efficient by using a reader/writer mutex, e.g.

```
boost::shared_mutex          mutex_;
std::unordered_set<UpdateID> set_;

void onUpdate(const Update& update)
{
    boost::upgrade_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(mutex_);

    auto it = set_.find(update.id);
    if(it == set_.end())
    {
        boost::upgrade_to_unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> unique_lock(mutex_);
        set.insert(update.id);
    }

    listener->onUpdate(/*some stuff*/);
}
```

Comment: In what way does this change things for OP? With your code either both threads block at `lock(mutex_)` (as in OP's example) or will insert twice in a race. Don't you want to re-check `set_.find()` after taking `unique_lock(mutex_)` thus making it a DCLP?

Comment: lock(mutex_) will not block unless an upgraded "write" lock exists, thus it is more efficient than OP example and reliable (unlike DCLP). Please read about multiple-readers single-writer mutexes.

Comment: Why would you need to re-check `find`? If the item already exists `insert` does nothing.

Comment: you're right. Please edit your answer (with a minor change) so that I can take back my downvote. Sorry.

Comment: Reader Writer seems reasonable, though I think the upgrade operation will occur the vast majority of the time, but I'll look into this as well thank you

Answer (score 0):

So you just continually add entries to your hash table? Never removing them? What does your hash table load look like? With enough collisions, your insert/lookup performance will degrade.

If your stream has sequence numbers, I would think you'd do better to track gaps (missing sequence numbers) instead of messages you've actually seen. On the fast UDP side when sequence numbers have gaps record the missing messages in the hash table and call onUpdate() on every message you receive. On the slow TCP side, look in the hash table to see if a message fills a gap, if it does call onUpdate() and remove that message from the hash table, otherwise do nothing.

That said, a lock-free hash table is possible. Not sure they are lock-free, but Microsoft has [concurrent_unordered_map](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh750089) (and [concurrent_unordered_set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh750108)) and TBB has [concurrent_hash_map](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/files/documentation/a00130.html).

Answer (score -1):

There is the [double-check-locking design-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) where you avoid expensive locking by checking the insert condition two times. But what is more expensive: locking or finding.

Comment: As far as I know there is no portable implementation of DCLP on C++.

Comment: @ronag Please elaborate in what way this disqualifies the DCLP being used by the OP? I more than willing to learn.

Comment: Without knowing how the "set" is implemented there is no way to know whether DCLP will behave as intended, e.g. the thread inserting into the set could be suspended during the insert operation, but still return true for the find for another thread. You can read more about the hazards of DCLP http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf.